# php variables help with a big number

Tags: php, variables, numbers

Hello i need to know if php there is a variable type that doesn't show me something like this:

3.9614081257132E+28

Please anyone knows how to make that?

Comment: You've got a display issue, not a variable type issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf) to print the variable:

```
echo sprintf("%f", 3.9614081257132E+28);
// prints 39614081257132001671004553216.00000
```

Or without the decimal digits:

```
echo sprintf("%.0f", 3.9614081257132E+28);
// prints 39614081257132001671004553216
```

---

If you need arbitrary precision numbers, try the **[bcmath](http://docs.php.net/bcmath)** and **[GMP](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php)** modules.

Answer (score 0):

What you get is just a standard way of displaying "long" real numbers.

for operations with those, you might also want to review this topic: [How to parse long value in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310164/how-to-parse-long-value-in-php/7310192#comment-8832837)

Answer (score 0):

There are no "big num" types in PHP.  However, there really isn't anything to stop you from building a class that is capable of representing a big integer.  You can do this with the string data type.