# Converting LONG to Int adds extra 0

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, integer, longtext

i do have really similar issues as in this topic: [Proper way of converting string to long int in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002152/proper-way-of-converting-string-to-long-int-in-php/38552558#38552558)

Unfortunately solution there is not working for me.

My situation is following:

I do have Wordpress database with meta_key which value is `700` (in LONGTEXT). I would like to get this number as Integer.

But when I use `intval($meta_value)` or even `(float) $meta_value` it adds extra zero to at the end and returns `7000` :(

Could someone please help?

EDIT: Screenshots added

here is picture of data in database
[image: here is picture of data in database]

here is code that loads this value and converts it
[image: here is code that loads this value and converts it]

But the site is still returning `7000`

Here is original code:

```
$meta_value = the_author_meta('pocet_bodu', $user_id);
                                    echo $meta_value;
```

This returns okay 700, but it is not number and it cannot be used for mathematical operations. Once I try to convert it to integer or float, number is 7000.

Comment: I have never heard of casting a long to an int resulting in multiplication by 10.  Can you show us some actual data here?

Comment: What if you cast it like this: `(int) $meta_value`

Comment: imo, I would: debugging: `var_dump($meta_value, bin2hex($meta_value), strlen($meta_value), intval($meta_value), (float) $meta_value, __FILE__.__LINE__));` Why? See what the actual data really is, not just the printable characters. Also, it is quick to do and easy to see what is happening.

Comment: Neither `(int) $meta_value` is not working for me. Screenshots of code added

Comment: Take  a look at the value before casting! Do a var_dump!

Comment: Ok, where does the 7000 come from? Not from $meta_value obviously?

Comment: This is what `var_dump` returns `NULL string(0) "" int(0) int(0) float(0) string(90)` `$meta_value` in my code is `$bodyUzivatele`

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun problem. Kindly change [the_author_meta()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/author-template.php) to [get_the_author_meta()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/author-template.php).

The former function will **echo** "700" (with no return value) and then you additionally `echo (int)` on that non-return value (effectively `(int)false`, if I'm not mistaken, which is 0). There is your 7000.